# Xpath python is not working

Tags: python, html, xpath

hi i am trying to get data from xxx website through python xpath...it just give me blank data.. i copied the xpath from chrome.. pls let me know what i am doing wrong here. Thanks you

```
from lxml import html,etree
import requests
import urllib2
def webText(url):
    import urllib2
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    return html
x=webText("http://www.sportscardforum.com/ttm.php?s=3161e010cc6e6fd80ddb2e6b18ab2c5d&do=listp&pl=13450&sp=4");
f = open("foo.html", "w");
f.write(x) 
f.close()

R=open("foo.html").read().strip()
tree =etree.HTML(R)
x = tree.xpath('//*[@id="vbulletin_html"]/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]')
print x
```

Comment: can u tell us that which value you want to extract? means which field from interface? because it is hard to understand from given xpath

Comment: above xpath is for Address: line if you open the url u will see the address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to first write the html to a file and then read that file again. Example below gets the data you're after,

```
import requests
import urllib2
from lxml import html, etree

def webText(url):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    return html

data = webText("http://www.sportscardforum.com/ttm.php?s=3161e010cc6e6fd80ddb2e6b18ab2c5d&do=listp&pl=13450&sp=4");
tree = etree.HTML(data)

info = tree.xpath("//b[contains(text(),'Address:')]/ancestor::tr[1]//table//td[1]/text()")

for i in info:
    print i
```

Comment: thanks man... it work fine and yes i don't have to write it on file.....can you tell me how did you get this xpath?

Comment: I got it by trial and error. In the console of Chrome and Firefox (firebug) you can play around with xpaths like so `$x("//your-xpath-here")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following xpath:

```
//b[contains(text(),'Address:')]/parent::td[1]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

Comment: out put is this -->[<Element td at 0x2915fa8>] how i can use this ??

Comment: try it   :   //b[contains(text(),'Address:')]/parent::td[1]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()